# HtmlUnit does not return all headers

Tags: htmlunit

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(webPageURL);

        final String pageAsXml = page.asXml();
        final String pageAsText = page.asText();


        List <NameValuePair> response = page.getWebResponse().getResponseHeaders();
        for (NameValuePair header : response) {
            log.info(header.toString() + " = " + header.getValue());
```

The web page returns more than one header. But the log shows only the first header. How do I get rest of headers? The header I am looking for is of Content Type: application/javascript;charset=ISO-8859-1

The web page is an internal web page.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided is working for me. Actually, I replaced the `header.toString()` for `header.getName()`:

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
final HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.debian.org");
List<NameValuePair> response = page.getWebResponse().getResponseHeaders();
for (NameValuePair header : response) {
    System.out.println(header.getName() + " = " + header.getValue());
}
```

The output is:

```
Date = Thu, 22 Aug 2013 19:48:54 GMT
Server = Apache
Content-Location = index.en.html
Vary = negotiate,accept-language,Accept-Encoding
TCN = choice
Last-Modified = Thu, 22 Aug 2013 15:31:17 GMT
ETag = "3887-4e48afb257b40"
Accept-Ranges = bytes
Cache-Control = max-age=86400
Expires = Fri, 23 Aug 2013 19:48:54 GMT
Content-Encoding = gzip
Content-Length = 4605
Keep-Alive = timeout=15, max=100
Connection = Keep-Alive
Content-Type = text/html
Content-Language = en
```

As you can see, the `Content-Type` header is there. Can you confirm the server is actually sending that piece of data (it is a common header so it should).